# Is it possible to embed a YouTube video using LaTeX?

Tags: pdftex, embedding, movie15

I'd like to embed a YouTube video inside a PDF generated by LaTeX, now I know it is possible to embed videos using the `movie15` package but that includes the video in the PDF.

I was hoping there would be some way to embed the video as a flash object that streams it from YouTube when you get to the slide.

Anyone managed to do it before?

Comment: Are there PDF viewers which support Flash? The embedding is only the first half. The viewer must support it as well.

Comment: @Martin latest Acrobat can embed flash video, no idea if it can stream it though

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Edit

> **Notice of obsolescence:**
>
> YouTube have dropped their Flash-based video player in Sept 2017. For
> the lack of HTML5 support in the PDF specification (and thus by PDF
> viewers), YT playback is not possible anymore in an embedded fashion.

Alternatively, the **SVG** format allows embedded playback of HTML5 video, including **YouTube** and **Vimeo**. Package [`media4svg`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/media4svg) is available for this purpose. It requires a workflow via DVI (`dvilualatex`/`latex` + `dvisvgm`). Example: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media4svg/example/beamer-example-3.svg

---

### Original answer

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}             %pdflatex, latex+dvips+ps2pdf, xelatex
%\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{media9}  %latex+dvipdfmx

\begin{document}
\includemedia[
  width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.45\linewidth,
  activate=pageopen,
  flashvars={
    modestbranding=1 % no YT logo in control bar
   &autohide=1       % controlbar autohide
   &showinfo=0       % no title and other info before start
  }
]{}{http://www.youtube.com/v/<video id>?rel=0}   % Flash file
\end{document}
```

`<video id>` to be replaced by the video ID, i. e., something like `Mdc3o7wOwNA`. More FlashVars for configuring the youtube video player are documented [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html). Some FlashVars, such as `rel=0`, seem to have effect only if appended to the URL.

Comment: Only downside: it doesn't seem to be working with the Linux version of Acrobat Reader 9 :(

Comment: @PierreBdR: Yeah, they (Adobe) seem to have abandoned further development of AR on the Linux platform. Last thing they did was disabling the embedded FlashPlayer :(.

Comment: It might be due to updates of the packages between your post and now, but it gives the error `! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \__scan_new:N 
                              
l.54 \__scan_new:N
                   \s__tl`

Comment: @Betohaku : At least version 0.24 as of 2013-02-21 of media9 is required.

Comment: I get the same error as @PierreBdR when formatting the above code using MiKTeX v2.9 and the latest version of media9. I replaced the <video id> with a video ID. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @TomPrice Linux versions of Adobe Reader don't support Flash and multimedia any more, only Win and Mac.

Comment: @TomPrice You also need to update l3packages and l3kernal

Answer (score 9):

The [y4pdf package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/yt4pdf/) is [no more] what you need !

EDIT : Please note this answer is now obsolete and this package does not seems to be supported anymore, and if you ever manage to compile the package, the resulting PDF won't play the video.

Comment: Oh, this wont work with `pdflatex` alone: "Rich media annotation is a feature of Acrobat/Adobe Reader version 9. Acrobat Pro and Distiller version 9.0 or later are required to build a document, and Adobe Reader 9.0 or later is needed to activate the annotation and play the media."

Comment: note that movie15 was superseded by media9, some time back.  we (ctan and karl berry) were assured by the author that media9 _does_ do the necessary with pdflatex, and that development for other viewers than acro* is underway.

Comment: @Magix Are you sure? Apart from the difficulties I encountered when I tried to compile any of the yt4pdf [examples](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/yt4pdf/examples) (too many requirements/dependencies, e.g. Acrobat Distiller, `acrotex`, `rmannot` packages), the method seems to be obsolete anyway, since the [pre-compiled examples](http://www.math.uakron.edu/~dpstory/yt4pdf.html) do not work anymore.

Comment: @AlexG i am not the author of this answer, i just edited it because it was terrible. So if you ask me, no, i'm not sure ;-)

Comment: @Magix: Well, the exclamation mark of your edited answer made me think you are a staunch user.

Comment: @AlexG not yet, but I'm actually trying it right now (actually, you are right, this answer is obsolete)

Answer (score 1):

Flash support has discontinued from Dec 2020.
At least  Media9 no longer works as above. Fixes are in [Alternatives](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516029/129388)

Answer (score 0):

maybe ltx4yt package may work.
Get it from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltx4yt