# How to install y4pdf package in Tex Live on Windows XP?

Tags: packages, installing, texlive, windows

I want to install `y4pdf` package to my `Tex Live 2010` distribution. The package itself is consisting of the following files according to http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/yt4pdf/:

- y4pdf.cfg
- y4pdf.dtx
- y4pdf.ins
- y4pdf.sty

Does anyone have experience where to put concrete files in order to make it work?

Comment: Instead of `yt4pdf`, which requires Acrobat Pro, I recommend the `media9` package for embedding Youtube videos. It is in TeXLive-2012 and in the imminent TeXLive-2013 (begin of July). It can be used with all common workflows (pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LaTeX+`dvips`+`ps2pdf`). See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97687. Don't use TeX-Live2010 anymore, it is very outdated.

Comment: Without a specific reason, I think this is just the general 'local install' question.