# How to embed a YouTube video or other streaming in HTML5 format?

Tags: media9, multimedia, video

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97687/69174) there was a good solution to the question [Is it possible to embed a YouTube video using LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14751/69174)

Unfortunately, since some days, it do not work more. The result, in the PDF, is this one:

[image: Result in the PDF]

obtained with `\usepackage{media9}` in the preamble and with this code:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \includemedia[
    width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.45\linewidth,
    activate=pageopen,
    flashvars={
        modestbranding=1  % no YT logo in control bar
        &autohide=1       % controlbar autohide
        &showinfo=0       % no title and other info before start
    }
    ]{}{http://www.youtube.com/v/CRgiA1XcRRg?rel=0}   % Flash file
    \caption{Zombie Nation---studio recording `Acid Yoga' con Roland System 700.}
    \label{fig:yt}
\end{figure}
```

This problem is caused because YouTube - as several other streaming services - do not support more Flash, and now use HTML5.

**There is somebody know a way to embed a YouTube streaming in a LaTeX document, now?**

Comment: What a pitty! Currently there is no support for HTML5 in the PDF specification, and thus no plugin at least for A-Reader available.

Comment: Do you know whether dropping Flash by YouTube was announced somewhere?

Comment: @AlexG Unfortunately yes: https://www.youtube.com/html5.

Comment: Well, this is only the announcement of the YT html5 player which coexisted with the YT Flash based player for several years.

Comment: Yes, but is the only that I have found. And in https://acrobatusers.com/forum/pdf-creation/embed-html5-videos-pdf/ I have read that "there is no longer a definition in the RFC as to what codecs should be supported, and many videos being posted to HTML5 sites at the moment use Google's "WebM" format - although Adobe have confirmed future support for this codec in Flash Player, it's not supported by Acrobat yet".

Comment: @AlexG This may be a pain in the ass for a moment, but ultimately we should refrain to use flash altogether. This is a step in the right direction and, frankly, it's kind of surprising that flash is still alive given its many flaws.

Comment: Ok, I can don't use flash but I'm still haven't found another solution. I simply search a way to embed a stream video in a pdf document via LaTeX.